# How to execute a PHP function inside of a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, php

I made a two PHP functions for my project, these two functions responsible for fetching different product category for different "online shop".

Now, I am implementing the function that when employee adding a new product, the employee first select which online shop does the new product belongs to (via a select), then depends on the online shop, the second select menu should display the correct options.

so, the first select looks like this

```
< Select name="Select_CCV_Webshop[]" id="ccv-webshop"        
onchange='loadNew_CCV_Category()'>
```

here I need help on how to execute `/call /trigger` the `php` function inside of method `"loadNew_CCV_Category"`.

Inside of function `"loadNew_CCV_Category"`, it will get the select value, and this value will be the parameters for the `php` function.

Please help :D, Thank you !!!!

Comment: show your code... it would be better to answer then...

Comment: Research [Javascript AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)

Comment: JavaScrpt runs client side. PHP Server side. You can try using AJAX like described in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757750/how-can-i-call-php-functions-by-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I call PHP functions by JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757750/how-can-i-call-php-functions-by-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute `php` inside `javascript`. because `php` is server side program and `javascript` is browser related.

If you want to write `php` then you can try this.

```
alert("<?php echo 'hello' ?>")
```

or

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'yourphpfilepath.php',
   success: function(respon) {
   $('.result').html(respon);
 }
});
```

your code will be like this.

```
<Select name="Select_CCV_Webshop[]" id="ccv-webshop" onchange='loadNew_CCV_Category()'>
<div id=wheretoshowresult> </div>

<script>
function loadNew_CCV_Category(){
  $.ajax({
   url: 'yourphpfilepath.php', //url for your php function or file
   success: function(respon) {
    $('#wheretoshowresult').html(respon);
   }
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: i have tried alert, but i don't need to show the alert, so I was confused, i will try second suggestion from you

Comment: if you could offer some example, that would be super! thank u

Comment: google for events in jquery and ajax... read both of the... I know your are new in this and it is getting difficult for you to understand the code... learn about ajax.. I will try to help you with some url http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/dynamic-select-option-menu-using-ajax-and-php.php

Comment: look at above url that I have given you in comment.. that will help you in detail...

Comment: the link above from talkers code is perfect, it works for me perfectly

Comment: but could you please help me more on this question?

Comment: if you got the answer than you will also understand my solution... and it worked for you than accept my answer if your problem is resolved...

Comment: There is nothing to help... it is more likely to understand one problem and then use it... if you want to send data data in ajax then also you will get solution and example online.. just google it and if you cannot find find it then get back to me...

Answer (score 0):

**The short answer**

You can not. PHP is executed server-side and only the PHP-generated page is then delivered to the browser, where JS takes over and can continue reacting to input, but only with information it already has.

**The more helpful answer**

You can, however, either deliver the information for both cases to the browser and decide which one should be shown, or, which in most cases will be what you would rather do, make another call to the server from within your JS.

That means you would have an additional PHP script, which executes the function and generates the page content you want to insert.

You would then access that script file using JS and insert the generated contents into your page.

As for how to do that, maybe 
[this answer might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21447827/load-a-php-query-file-in-an-html-index-page-using-ajax-or-jquery/21447893#21447893).

EDIT: Also refer to [Avi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51889723/how-to-execute-a-php-function-inside-of-a-javascript-function/51889835#51889835) on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way,

```
<?php
function square($num)
{   
    echo $num * $num;
} 
?>

<select name="Select_CCV_Webshop[]" id="ccv-webshop"
onchange='loadNew_CCV_Category()'>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option>Test Php</option>
</select>

<script>
    function loadNew_CCV_Category(){
        var phpData = "<?php square(4) ?>"
        alert(phpData);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: alert means you are getting the data, anyway thank you.